Proving all pure states on $\mathcal{B}(H)$ live inside the w* closure of the vector states
I'm reading Takesaki's Theory of Operator Algebras I and I'm stuck on one of the exercises. This is exercise 2 in Section 2 of Chapter II.
It says let $H$ be infinite dimensional, $V$ the set of vector states on $\mathcal{B}(H)$ and $\tilde{V}$ the w* closure of $V$ in $\mathcal{B}(H)^*.$ Let also $S_0$ be the set of all those states which vanish on the compacts.
First, he makes you prove $\tilde{V}\cap S_0$ is convex, then he asks to show all pure states are in $\tilde{V}$ and finally deduce that $S_0$ is fully contained in $\tilde{V}$.
I've done the first bit, and I can see how the last bit would follow, but I'm sturggling with proving all pure states are in $\tilde{V}$.
My first instinct would be to try Hahn-Banach, but $V$ isn't convex so that didn't lead anywhere. My only other thought is to "brute force" it: fix a pure state together with a generic w*-open neighbourhood and prove it intersects $V$. I could to this in a very particular case, but it wasn't particularly illuminating:
Specifically, if my state is $\omega$ and the open neighbourhood happens to be of the form $\{\phi \in \mathcal{B}(H)^*: |\omega(x)-\phi(x)|<\epsilon \}$ where furthermore $x$ is self adjoint then I can consider the map $\xi\to |\omega(x)-\langle{x\xi,\xi}\rangle|$ defined on the unit sphere of $H$. This is continuous, and as the sphere is sonnected, if it could be that $|\langle{(\omega(x)-x)\xi, \xi}\rangle|\geq \epsilon$ for all $||\xi||=1$ then either $\langle{(\omega(x)-x)\xi, \xi}\rangle\geq \epsilon$ for all $\xi$ or $\langle{(\omega(x)-x)\xi, \xi}\rangle\leq -\epsilon$ for all $\xi.$ This is a contradiction as e.g. in the first case it would imply $\omega(x)-x\geq \epsilon,$ which of course cannot happen as $\omega(\omega(x)-x)=0$ and $\omega$ is a state.
It would of course be enough if I could generalise this argument to work for more self-adjoint $x$'s at the same time, but the connectedness trick wouldn't work anymore. The bigger issue of course is that I'm not using here that $\omega$ is pure so I don't think this is the way to go.
If anyone has a suggestion as to how to go about proving the statement, I'd be very grateful.

I would start by proving the following lemma first.

Suppose that $A$ is a $C^{*}$-algebra and that $a \in A_{\text{sa}}$.  Then: $$\lVert a \rVert = \sup_{\rho \in S(A)} |\rho(a)|.$$  Moreover if $C \subset S(A)$ is a subset of the state space of $A$, and $D = \overline{\text{cohull}(C)}^{w^{*}}$, then $S(A) \subset D$ if and only if: $$\lVert a \rVert = \sup_{\rho \in C} |\rho(a)| \: \: \forall a \in A_{\text{sa}}.$$

You will indeed want to use Hahn-Banach separation for one of the directions here.  This lemma will actually prove that what you want is true for every non-degenerate $C^{*}$-subalgebra $A \subset \mathcal{B}(H)$.
One additional hint I would give is to recall that if $T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ is self adjoint, then $\lVert T \rVert = \text{nr}(T)$, where: $$\text{nr}(T) = \sup_{\lVert h \rVert \leq 1} |\langle Th,h \rangle|$$ is the numerical range of $T$.

I think I got it! I guess the point is too see all states live in the (w*-)closed convex hull of $V$ so by Milmann's Theorem the pure states actually have to live in $\tilde{V}$? Really nice argument actually, thanks for the help!
